# Match dates in Linq, C#, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime

I am using the repository pattern to query SQL to get a record based on a date passed in via a web api.  The query string is date=2014-09-16, for example.  When my repository receives this date, the time is automatically set to 12:00:00 since one wasn't passed.  I am only interested in matching the date in the database like this:

```
public IQueryable<Instance> GetInstances(DateTime date) {
        return DBContext.Instances.Where(x => x.StartDateTime == date).OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime).AsQueryable();
    }
```

The problem is that no match is found since the records in the db are not a full match because of the time portion even though records exist for this date.  What is the best way to get a match in the above example?

Comment: So why can't you use the method that is specifically designed to do exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, newbie.  I tried adding System.Data.Entity and then calling DbFunctions but i get an error that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What type of query provider are you using?  Are you using EF, linq to SQL, or something else?  You'll need to use functions that are specific to the query provider you're using.

Comment: Provide the actual query that you were using and the exact error message that you were getting.  And rather than saying you can't use it, you should be explaining what problems you're having using it, since you don't have some reason to prohibit people from using it, rather you need to figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Here are all the default .NET [methods EF supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738563(v=vs.100).aspx).  Only these are supported.  If you want something else, you have to use these date functions: [Entity Framework sqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx), or put your code in a stored procedure or table function (which can be called by the context).

Comment: He specifically said in the question that he didn't want to use the appropriate function you're referring to.

Comment: he said he didn't want to use DbFunctions.TruncateTime.  I proposed SqlFunctions, and most likely DateDiff, so technically speaking, that's different than the restriction originally mentioned.I also updated the question to include more specifics.